# Multiple Django projects, same domain name, same server apache

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi, apache-config

I have one Django project which is already hosted on domain name say example.com. And its home page is

> `example.com/demotool/`

Now I developed another Django project and want to host on the same apache server, same domain name, with different URL set.

For example, its root URL will be

> example.com/demotool/client1/

I have separate project_name.wsgi file for both projects.

Directory structure is like

```
/home/user/public_html/example.com/project/project_name.wsgi
/home/user/public_html/example.com/project1/project1_name.wsgi
```

content of wsgi file is

```
> import os import sys
> sys.path.append('/home/user/public_html/example.com/project/')
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings' 
> import django.core.handlers.wsgi
> application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

content of /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com is

```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>         ServerName example.com
>         ServerAlias www.example.com
>         WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/public_html/example.com/project/project_name.wsgi
>         Alias /static/ /home/user/public_html/example.com/project/static/
>         <Location "/static/">
>             Options -Indexes
>         </Location>
> </VirtualHost>
```

Now what should I add or modify in the apache configuration file to add another project in the same domain name and same server.
There are duplicates of this question but I don't get it how to make it work please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use a subdomain?

Comment: If it was my project, I would have preferred subdomain, but its the company in which I work, they want this way.
One way is that I can make it as a separate application inside the existing project, for now. and later try adding virtual host

Answer (score 1):

I've always done it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess project1-http python-home=/home/deployer/.virtualenvs/project1
    WSGIScriptAlias /project1 /var/www/html/project1/project1/wsgi.py process-group=project1-http application-group=project1-http
    WSGIProcessGroup project1-http
    Alias /project1/static/ /var/www/html/project1/static/

    WSGIDaemonProcess project2-http python-home=/home/deployer/.virtualenvs/project2
    WSGIScriptAlias /project2 /var/www/html/project2/project2/wsgi.py process-group=project2-http application-group=project2-http
    WSGIProcessGroup project2-http
    Alias /project2/static/ /var/www/html/project2/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this -:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
ServerName example.com
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /home/user/public_html/example.com/project/project_name.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /home/user/public_html/example.com/project1/project1_name.wsgi

<Directory /home/user/public_html/example.com/project>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/public_html/example.com/project1>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</virtualhost>
```

Comment in case something is still not working.   cheers :-)

Comment: Followed what you suggested, but when I restart apache I get this error,

Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/marketelligent.in:
order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow', or 'mutual-failure'
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!

There is error on the line which contains "Order allow, deny"

Thanks